# UITableView not being displayed after reloading data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a strange problem with my tableView.
I load data via JSON into my tableView. While the JSON is being requested from the web in another class, I show an activity indicator view in my current view and the tableView is hidden.
I ve got a delegate method, which is called as soon as the json is ready.

```
-(void)didReceivePlayers:(NSArray *)players {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    tableViewPlayers.hidden = false;
    startButton.hidden = false;
    playersData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:players];
    [tableViewPlayers reloadData];
    NSLog(@"done reloading"); 
}
```

The method is being called  perfectly. 
The code is pretty straight forward. I hide my activity indicator and show my tableView. 
Then I call reloadData. It takes only a few milliseconds. BUT after reloadData, my activityIndicator is still shown and it takes several seconds to show my tableview, although the nslog is being called right away.

I also tried calling reload data in mainThread, but this did not change a thing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Both the UI updates, like `startButton.hidden = false` and the `reloadData` *must* be done on the main thread.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I only tried reloadData in the mainThread. But the UI changes caused the weird behavior. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that the code is being executed on the main thread. You can use the main operation queue like this:

```
-(void)didReceivePlayers:(NSArray *)players {

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        tableViewPlayers.hidden = false;
        startButton.hidden = false;
        playersData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:players];
        [tableViewPlayers reloadData];
        NSLog(@"done reloading");
    }];

}
```